# Fill Svg Path with rects

Tags: javascript, svg, path

i am in a situation where i need to Fill Svg path with different rects.  here 'different' means each rect will be a separate svg element, and i can access it using id i.e document.getElementById('rect_');

I cannot use 'Patterns' because they fill path but i can't access each element separately .

let say i have path :-

```
  <path d="M 10 10 L 50 10 80 125Z" stroke="red" fill='none' />
```

Now i need to fill this path with rects. Rect specs are:-

```
<rect x=0 y=0 width=5 height= 5 stroke="red" />
```

*I can convert path into points (x y cordinates) but unable to make logic to create rects inside that path.

**Explanation:-**

Let me explain the whole senerio ,  i am developing an application in svg in which user can draw his custom path (just like painting) , once he finishes his drawing, path will be closed and then i need to fill that path with 'n' number of 'rects' . now i need to determine how many rects will be drawn and at what place .  Rects must be inside that path area.

I need help on this,

thanks.

Comment: My goal is to create rects inside the path area. Rect width height is fixed, so i need to fill path with multiple rects in such a way that all rects are inside that path.

Comment: So find the bounding box of the path and then create rect elements to fill that area.

Comment: Your question isn't that clear. Your example path is a single line segment. Are you trying to put rects inside the stroke or fill of the path? Also, what exactly are you having trouble with? Working out which part of the image will be "Inside" the path?

Comment: i have added some explanation and also update the path cordinates, please check now. thanks.